# Program keeps redirecting to home page after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring Security to my program and the instructions we were given had all information from deprecated classes that aren't used anymore so I am trying to figure out how to properly update my code. I currently go to my home page localhost:8080 click the login hyper link then I am redirected to localhost:8080/login. I enter the correct username and password but then am redirected back to localhost:8080 instead of localhost:8080/display/orders.

Is there something wrong in my security class? Or is there not the correct redirecting happening in my controllers?

Here is my security config

```
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/images/**", "/service/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/orders/display", true)
                
            )
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll());
        
        return http.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test").password("{noop}test").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Here are my controllers

```
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrdersController {

    @Autowired
    private OrdersBusinessService service;

    @GetMapping("/display")
    public String display(Model model) {
        List<OrderModel> orders = service.getOrders();
        model.addAttribute("title", "My Orders");
        model.addAttribute("orders", orders);
        return "orders";
    }
    
}
```

```
public class LoginController {
    
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String display(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Login Form");
        return "login";
    }
```

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "My Home");
        return "home";
    }
}
```